# How to perform if...else statement associating with sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Can i create if...else statement that will affects my sql? Below is my code right now
SQL statement

```
$sql= "SELECT  * FROM   maklumatakaun 
        LEFT JOIN detailakaun ON maklumatakaun.id = detailakaun.id 
        LEFT JOIN maklumatbilakaun ON maklumatakaun.NoAkaun = maklumatbilakaun.NoAkaun 
        LEFT JOIN kodjenisakaun ON detailakaun.KodJenisAkaun = kodjenisakaun.KodJenisAkaun
        LEFT JOIN kodlokasi ON detailakaun.KodLokasi = kodlokasi.KodLokasi
        LEFT JOIN kodkategori ON maklumatakaun.KodKategori = kodkategori.KodKategori        
        LEFT JOIN koddaerah ON maklumatakaun.KodDaerah = koddaerah.KodDaerah
        WHERE maklumatakaun.KodKategori = '$KodKategori' 
        AND detailakaun.KodJenisAkaun = '$KodJenisAkaun'
        AND maklumatakaun.KodDaerah = '$KodDaerah' 
        AND maklumatbilakaun.BulanBil = '$BulanBil' 
        AND maklumatbilakaun.TahunBil ='$TahunBil' 
        GROUP BY maklumatakaun. NoAkaun ";
```

user can select which 'daerah' report they want to see by selecting in the drop down box which contains options from the database

```
<?php include('dbase.php');
$sql = "SELECT KodDaerah, NamaDaerah FROM koddaerah";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select name='KodDaerah' id='KodDaerah' class='input_field' required />
<option>Pilih Daerah</option>
<option value='all'>Seluruh Pahang</option>";
while ($kod = mysql_fetch_array ($result)){
echo "<option value=".$kod['KodDaerah'].">" .$kod['NamaDaerah']."</option>";
}
echo "<?select>";
?>
```

So lets say they want to see ALL daerah, how can i do that? They can select 'all' in the drop down box but then how i should write my if...else statement?

Comment: I would just get all results and use AJAX to sort them

Comment: Why the GROUP BY when no aggregate functions (MAX, SUM, COUNT etc) are involved? Consider SELECT DISTINCT * FROM... if you want to remove duplicate rows.

Comment: can i not use AJAX? because i dont really have the knowledge on AJAX

Comment: Ofcourse it's possible without AJAX but your question is a little unclear. What are daerahs? Are they in tables? columns? Is it possible to select them in the WHERE clause?

Comment: DAERAH are malay for DISTRICT user would select from the drop down box which have data from the table koddaerah. Column for koddaerah are KodDaerah AND NamaDaerah @SinanSamet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest thing in my opinion (maybe a little messy) would be to add a where variable to the sql

```
   $where = '';
    $sql= "SELECT  * FROM   maklumatakaun 
            LEFT JOIN detailakaun ON maklumatakaun.id = detailakaun.id 
            LEFT JOIN maklumatbilakaun ON maklumatakaun.NoAkaun = maklumatbilakaun.NoAkaun 
            LEFT JOIN kodjenisakaun ON detailakaun.KodJenisAkaun = kodjenisakaun.KodJenisAkaun
            LEFT JOIN kodlokasi ON detailakaun.KodLokasi = kodlokasi.KodLokasi
            LEFT JOIN kodkategori ON maklumatakaun.KodKategori = kodkategori.KodKategori        
            LEFT JOIN koddaerah ON maklumatakaun.KodDaerah = koddaerah.KodDaerah
            WHERE maklumatakaun.KodKategori = '$KodKategori' 
            AND detailakaun.KodJenisAkaun = '$KodJenisAkaun'
            AND maklumatbilakaun.BulanBil = '$BulanBil' 
            AND maklumatbilakaun.TahunBil ='$TahunBil' 
            ".mysql_real_escape_string($where)."
            GROUP BY maklumatakaun. NoAkaun ";



if($KodDaerah != 'all'){
  $where .= "AND maklumatakaun.KodDaerah = '$KodDaerah' "; //Add your where statement here
  //Whatever you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want to know...

```
SELECT IF(column_1 = 5, 'if value is 5 ', 'else') FROM table_name;
```

You can also use this in WHERE clause.